# How does Gower distance work with free text?

Tags: clustering, text-mining, distance-functions, gower-similarity

The Gower distance measure is a good measure for mixed-type data (i.e., data attributes can be qualitative, categorical, ordinal or binary). But can data attributes be free-text (e.g., names of people)? I understand that string edit distance is a better measure for comparing free-text, but I have a table of records, where every column (attribute) in the table has a different type. I want to compute a similarity matrix of the table (pairwise record comparisons) for clustering. Gower distance seems suitable, except I'm not sure if it can handle free-text strings.

I understand that I can just perform Gower on all the attributes except the free-text string columns, and perhaps add the string edit distance as a normalized component to the overall distance measure. But I want to know if Gower can handle free-text strings. Or any other suggestions for mixed-type distance measures are appreciated.

Comment: 1) Gower can take scale (quantitative), ordinal, binary, nominal attributes. If you can present text as either of these types, then it is OK. 2) Special distance measures have been proposed specifically for text.

Comment: I cannot represent names of a population of people as quantitative, ordinal, binary, nominal attributes. I understand that there are many distance measures for text. However, I need to compute similarity for mixed-type objects, where text is only 1 of the attributes of the object. Other attributes of my object might be nominal, numeric, etc. The resulting similarity matrix will be used to cluster my objects of the table.

Comment: Do you really want to cluster your data based on text similarities of people names? It could be done, but for many (most?) use-cases it would be better to treat all names as equally distant, so that clustering happens on all the other data values that actually matter for your results.  Alternatively, you might want to split names in parts, so that people with matching surnames get clustered together, but again, looking only at identical surnames instead of your algorithm saying that Smith is more similar to Singh than to Thompson.

Comment: Those are valid points. My use case is very specific though.

Comment: I hope you know how Gower similarity is computed. It is a compositional, hodge-podge measure. Then nothing prevents you from computing a specialized text-similarity measure ranging from 0 to 1 and adding it to Gower's formula.

Comment: I see. I might either do that or maybe look for a different way for computing my similarity matrix. It's interesting that you call it a hodge-podge measure. Is there any paper which says the same about Gower similarity? Thanks for your advice btw.